# Sum of Uniform Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $X$ is a randomly selected real number in the range $[0,1]$, where $X$ follows a uniform distribution. Define $C_n(t)$ to be

$$C_n(t)=\Pr(\sum_{k=1}^n X_k \leq t)$$

In other words, $C_n(t)$ is the probability that the sum of $n$ real numbers randomly selected in the range $[0,1]$ is smaller than $t$. Let's also define a validity function $V(s,\ t)$.

$$V(s,\ t)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $0 \leq s \leq t$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Based on the validity function, $C_n(t)$ can be written as:
$$C_1(t)=P(X_1 < t)=\int_0^1 V(x_1,\ t)\ dx_1$$
$$C_2(t)=P(X_1 + X_2 < t)=\int_0^1\int_0^1 V(x_1+x_2,\ t)\ dx_1\ dx_2$$
$$C_3(t)=P(X_1 + X_2 + X_3 < t)=\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1 V(x_1+x_2+x_3,\ t)\ dx_1\ dx_2\ dx_3$$

And so on. I think the pattern of integration is pretty obvious. I was able to carry out the integration, attaining the following results:

$$C_1(t)=\begin{cases}
0 & t\leq 0 \\
t & 0< t \leq 1 \\
1 & t>1
\end{cases}$$

$$C_2(t)=\begin{cases}
0 & t\leq 0 \\
\frac{1}{2}t^2 & 0< t \leq 1 \\
-\frac{1}{2}t^2+2t - 1 & 1< t \leq 2\\
1 & t>2
\end{cases}$$

$$C_3(t)=\frac{1}{6}\begin{cases}
0 & t\leq 0 \\
t^3 & 0<t\leq 1 \\
-2t^3+9t^2-9t+3 & 1<t\leq 2\\
x^3-9x^2+27x-21 & 2<t\leq 3\\
6 & t > 3
\end{cases}$$

At which point the integration becomes somewhat arduous. What's the most efficient way to find a formula for a given $C_n(t)$? I realize that for large values of $n$, the function $C_n(t)$ is well approximated by the cumulative distribution function for the normal distribution (as per the central limit theorem), however I'm interested in the general calculation of $C_n(t)$

Comment: Instead of writing $Probability$ you can use the mathjax $\Pr$ that is written as `\Pr`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution
It is tedious to do by hand in general, not sure if you mean you want to find the optimal algorithm to compute the probabilities. When $n$ is large, the value can be approximated via CLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the [Irwin-Hall Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution) is defined to be sum of $n$ i.i.d. r.v.'s that are each $X_i\sim\text{Unif}(0,1)$. You want the cdf of this, which is:
$$C_n(x) = F_X(x;n) = \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor x\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(x-k)^n$$

The pdf of this is derived [here](http://www.randomservices.org/random/special/IrwinHall.html), which can be integrated to get the above.